# How to get all emails from a time stamp in mail.uid python

Tags: python, email, imap, imaplib

I know how to get all mails since a specific day:

```
import datetime
date = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, '(SENTSINCE {date})'.format(date=date))
```

i can't get mails from a specific timestamp. My attempt has been:

```
import datetime
date = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=24)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, '(SENTSINCE {date})'.format(date=date))
```

but i get the following error:

```
error: UID command error: BAD ['Could not parse command']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMAP search grammar does not support times. Only dates. It is a protocol limitation. See RFC 3501 for search syntax.

Comment: There's always a hack... a UID SEARCH DATE 15-jun-2015 HEADER "Date" ":24:48" searches for mail sent on 2015-06-15 x:24:48 for any x. At least it should not have many false positives. :24:48 can't be much other than minute and second because of the colons. The hack won't work on the hour field because of timezone issues (and yeah, I know, the Indian and Nepali timezones break this hack too, bah).

Comment: Besides this is using date and time from two different sources, which will lead to problems this only allows for exact matches, not since (greater than) matches..